# NSFetchRequest's fetchBatchSize causes all batches to be fetched immediately in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, core-data

I'm unable to make NSFetchRequest's `fetchBatchSize` work correctly. I'm testing with:

- Swift 3.0, Xcode 8.2.1, macOS 10.12 SDK, OS X 10.11.6
- Swift 3.1, Xcode 8.3 b4, macOS 10.12 SDK, macOS 10.12.3

**Behavior in Objective-C works as expected.** The returned `fetchResults` array correctly executes fetch requests in batches of 20 as items are accessed in the returned array. Profiling using the Core Data instrument or using `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` flags show this behavior.

**Behavior in Swift appears broken.** After executing the fetch request and storing it in the `fetchResults` variable, a series of fetch requests are automatically made in batches of 20, without any additional code accessing the returned `fetchResults` array. Perhaps Swift is making copy of the array or otherwise somehow accessing each element in the array, thus triggering the automatic batching for the entire array?

The `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3` option shows each batch fetch request as:

```
2017-03-10 20:57:23.698 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: annotation: Bound intarray _Z_intarray0
2017-03-10 20:57:23.699 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: details: Bound intarray value 1 at 0
2017-03-10 20:57:23.700 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: details: Bound intarray value 2 at 1
2017-03-10 20:57:23.700 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: details: Bound intarray value 3 at 2
2017-03-10 20:57:23.700 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: details: Bound intarray value 4 at 3
…
2017-03-10 20:57:23.728 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: details: Bound intarray value 20 at 19
2017-03-10 20:57:23.728 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: annotation: Bound intarray values.
2017-03-10 20:57:23.728 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME FROM ZITEM t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)   LIMIT 20
2017-03-10 20:57:23.730 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0316s
2017-03-10 20:57:23.730 TestApp[25937:5366493] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x60800008dc00> on entity 'Item' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME FROM ZITEM t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN (SELECT * FROM _Z_intarray0)   LIMIT 20' returned 20 rows with values: (
    "<Item: 0x6080000aa380> (entity: Item; id: 0x40000b <x-coredata://7B347406-2EDA-465D-B002-B392D3DE9CF4/Item/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    …
    "<Item: 0x6080000aa740> (entity: Item; id: 0x500000b <x-coredata://7B347406-2EDA-465D-B002-B392D3DE9CF4/Item/p20> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

What could be going on here? As long as the fetch request is executed in Objective-C, the returned array can be handed to Swift code and the batching works properly when the array elements are accessed. It's only when the fetch request is executed in Swift that the behavior is incorrect.

Objective-C:

```
- (NSArray<Item *> *)fetch {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Item"];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    return fetchResults;
}
```

Swift:

```
func fetch() -> [Item] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20
    let fetchResults = (try? self.context.fetch(request)) ?? []
    return fetchResults
}
```

The fetch is executed and the results and stored in a property.

```
var items: [Item]!

func fetchItems() {
    if let fetcher = SwiftFetcher(context: document.managedObjectContext) {
        items = fetcher.fetch()
    }
}
```

**My current workaround** involves writing a custom FetchedBatchArray class that wraps a Swift array and constructs and executes fetch requests as elements in the array are accessed, populating the backing array as objects are fetched from the store. This provides a way to achieve similar fetching behaviour that is comparable to using `NSFetchRequest`'s `fetchBatchSize`, but it doesn't require anything to be written in Objective-C. It also avoids the subtlety of encountering this bug when bridging to Swift.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift `Array` type is a value type, and the automatic bridging from `NSArray` to Swift array basically iterates through the entire array and copies the elements into a new Swift array. The same thing can happen if you call `po array` from the debugger.

If you leave the return type of the `fetch` method as `NSArray<Item>`, the elements won't need to be iterated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Swift imports NSManagedObjectContext's fetch method as `public func fetch<T : NSFetchRequestResult>(_ request: NSFetchRequest<T>) throws -> [T]` returning the Swift array (value type). As soon as that method is executed, the objects are iterated and the batching occurs for the entire array. I'm not sure how to get around this using only Swift, NSArray cannot be specialized in Swift as because Swift doesn't import it as generic. That rules out using NSArray<Item> for the return type unfortunately.